# What is the meaning of this statement in Java Servlets?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I read this statement about doGet method ()

> Make sure that the doHead method you write is both safe and idempotent (that is, protects itself from being called multiple times for one HTTP HEAD request).

What does the above statement mean and what has to be taken care of from a programming perspective?

I am making a single call to the backend server and the servlet at the backend is making repeated calls to itself. So I am trying to understand if that has to do anything with this statement above.

Please help me understand.

Comment: where is that statement from?

Comment: @JensSchauder: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

Comment: This could help   http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/

Comment: It's very poor wording. Idempotence doesn't mean 'protects itself', it is a property of the transaction, i.e. that it can be harmlessly repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

head() is automatically overriden when override doget() .A HEAD request is a GET request that returns no body in the response, only the request header fields.

> Make sure that the doHead method you write issafe

The GET method should be safe, that is, without any side effects for which users are held responsible. For example, most form queries have no side effects. If a client request is intended to change stored data, the request should use some other HTTP method.

> Make sure that the doHead method you write is idempotent

GET method should also be idempotent, meaning that it can be safely repeated. Sometimes making a method safe also makes it idempotent. For example, repeating queries is both safe and idempotent, but buying a product online or modifying data is neither safe nor idempotent.

JavaDoc explains it clearly : [doget()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

> Idempotence of a function:

Idempotence  is the property of certain operations in mathematics and computer science, that they can be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the initial application.Idempotent means that doing the request 10 times has the same effect as doing it once. An idempotent request might create something in a database the first time, but it won’t do it again. Or it’ll just return the reference to it the next time around.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are serving static contents through your servlet implementation and want do improve client, network and server performance leveraging browser cache you should not care about doHead method! Otherwise you should serve a empty body with right http headers (for example: Last-Modified etc..).

Answer (score 0):

"idempotent" means the method can be safely repeated and without any side effects.
because client usual use head method to detecting the resource info,such as existing, length,mediatype,modify time etc.